# Deleting closed questions with no answers

Tags: discussion

I don't think there any reason why we shouldn't delete questions like [these](https://serverfault.com/search?tab=newest&q=answers%3a0%20closed%3a1%20migrated%3a0). They are closed, have no answers and are very unlikely to get reopened - they (largely*) have no value. The

It takes 3 votes from 10k users to delete these types of post. Are other people with >= 10k prepared to join in? The more the better really as delete votes are hard to come by 10k=5 11k=6 12k=7 to a max of 30.

I've cast all of my delete votes on page 22 and 21 from the bottom up over the last couple of days.

I found the rules for [automagic deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006)

**If the question is more than `30` days old, and ...**

- has -1 or lower score
- has no answers
- is not locked

... it will be automatically deleted.

**If the question is more than `365` days old, and ...**

- has a score of 0 *or* a score of 1 with a deleted owner
- has no answers
- is not locked
- has a viewcount <= the age of the question in days times 1.5
- has 1 or 0 comments

... it will be automatically deleted.

**EDIT**

I have been down voting questions on the list with 'unused' votes at the end of my day. The automagic purge happened sometime early Saturday morning and a lot of questions on the list have now gone. This seems like the most effective way to get the job done.

If you have votes to use up **^** then going [**here**](https://serverfault.com/search?tab=newest&q=answers%3a0%20closed%3a1%20migrated%3a0) and down voting questions that are `above -1` would really help with the clean up.

*Some are merged and have the delete option removed.

**^** upvoting great questions and answers would be better.

Comment: I am willing to cast lots of delete votes if there is no automated way., but as @voretaq7, lets start with the oldest.

Answer (score 6):

They're already auto-deleted. I think it's 1 year with no answers and low views.

In any case, I'm up for deleting crap...

Comment: I thought that too but some are still about from 2009.

Comment: It's no answers, low views, and 0 or 1 upvotes. I think. So if you want to get rid of an older one and you don't have close-votes, just downvote.

Answer (score 6):

I have no problem with this -- There should probably be a "Delete" tab analogous to the "Close" tab on /review to make this easier.

**ETA:** It's probably most logical to start with the oldest questions and work our way forward...

Answer (score 0):

I've been sorting this list by votes and going to the back instead of sorting by date. The negatively voted stuff from this is *all* worth deleting.

Comment: I've been using my unused votes at the end of my day to downcheck questions on the list so that they get automagically deleted as per the edit to my post question.