# Let's love some older questions, ok?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, old-questions

I've been [killing bad closed questions](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/2291/deleting-closed-questions-with-no-answers) like a good boy and decided to slightly modify the search terms from there to find unloved questions that *aren't* closed in my favorite tags. The following query returned ~150 results, and many are answerable (some definitely deserve to be closed too. It's not all rosy).

> [active-directory] answers:0 closed:0 migrated:0

What do you say we make a concerted effort to answer some of these old questions that are hanging around in our favorite tags? Chances are that the OPs have given up, but that doesn't mean that these can't still be valuable to the community. If we all try and answer 2-3 of these per-day in our favorite tags, they'll be gone in no time and we can VTC the bad ones while we're at it, to aid in the great deletion of 2011.

Comment: Plus, it's good for badge-whoring if you're into that kind of thing.

Comment: No. No love. Only hate. HAAAAAAAAATES the questions, they steal the preciouses!

Comment: Whose turn was it to put @voretaq7 down for his nap today and why didn't it happen?

Comment: I don't know but I'm cranky! And which one of you hid my tequila?! Filthy tricksy thieveseses!  (then again maybe I'm just bitter because all the unanswered stuff on the FreeBSD tag is junk)

Comment: For the badge-whores, I've gotten 4 revivals in the last 24 hours by answering completely neglected questions that there was nothing wrong with.

Comment: TESTIFY @MarkM! PREACH IT BROTHER!

Answer (score 4):

Excellent idea for cleanup!

Comment: Look at you trying to get the number of unanswered questions on meta reduced. Have an upvote.