# How long before a closed question is deleted?

Tags: discussion

How long before a closed question is deleted? or is it ever deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/2291/deleting-closed-questions-with-no-answers) (credit to Iain) :

**If the question is more than `30` days old, and ...**

- has -1 or lower score
- has no answers
- is not locked

... it will be automatically deleted.

**If the question is more than `365` days old, and ...**

- has a score of 0 *or* a score of 1 with a deleted owner
- has no answers
- is not locked
- has a viewcount <= the age of the question in days times 1.5
- has 1 or 0 comments

... it will be automatically deleted.

OR

It will be deleted if three users with the appropriate amount of rep vote to delete it.

Comment: Or if it is flagged for deletion and the mod handling the flag agrees.

Comment: Hmmm....would this be something additional to add to the FAQ?

Comment: @mdpc Might be worth considering as a network-wide additional page for the FAQ (not sure what I'd call it though)

Comment: I believe that last line about only requiring three votes is somewhat incorrect. e.g. That horrible question about favourite server names. When I cast my vote to delete I was informed that it would take something like another 210 votes for it to be deleted. At the time there weren't that many SF people with voting rights.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers This is true. Questions with large amounts of votes need more delete votes. I believe 3 is the baseline for a "normal" closed question. You're definitely right that it's not always the case, though.

Answer (score 0):

Further information

The question lifecycle http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/the-stack-overflow-question-lifecycle/

and votes required to delete more popular questions

[Should delete votes be limited like close votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes)